# Request features within a polygon from PostGIS or GeoPackage with PyQGIS

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, geopackage

With the PyQGIS API, I have a QgsVectorLayer object that is sometimes a GeoPackage/SHP layer, sometimes a PostGIS layer. I have a working code to get all features within a given polygon "frame" when the layer is from a GeoPackage, but when it is from PostGIS so spatial filtering is server-side (the layer has a spatial index), `QgsFeatureRequest` functions `setFilterRect` or `setDistanceWithin` don't work anymore.

My code:

```
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(frame.boundingBox())
for feature in vectorLayer.getFeatures(request):
    if feature.geometry().intersects(frame):
        # feature stuff here
        id = str(feature.attribute(idFieldId))
```

For PostGIS case, I tried to use an spatial filter in `setFilterExpression` function but this doesn't get any feature:

```
spatialFilter = f"ST_Within({layer.dataProvider().uri().geometryColumn()}, ST_GeomFromText('{frame.asWkt()}', {frameSrid}))"
request.setFilterExpression(spatialFilter)
```

So, how to make a working and efficient spatial request with `QgsFeatureRequest` with a PostGIS layer?

Anyway, I can switch code depending on layer source provider with `layer.dataProvider().name()` which is `ogr` or `postgres`.

Comment: What does it mean: "QgsFeatureRequest functions setFilterRect or setDistanceWithin don't work anymore"? Does the script freeze or throw an error? I make your request to PostGIS, everything works for me, as with other vector layers.

Comment: It seems to me that you do not need the line `if feature.geometry().intersects(frame):` - this is not a necessary check, the request already checks which features will intersect with bbox.

Comment: OK, after holidays, I finally found what was wrong: the main error was in my sql where clause, so it's normal that nothing was selected spatially. Thanks for your answers. Actually, my 'frame' is oriented from the North, so if the bounding box is bigger than the polygon, so it's useful to check if feature geometry intersects the frame after request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `QgsFeatureRequest` spatial filtering works the same way with `ogr` and `postgres` layers. There is no need to separate the building of the request for each layer provider, and no need to use PostGIS SQL functions.

If the frame is oriented from the North (my case), so it is a polygon, spatial filter can be built using `setDistanceWithin` with a distance of zero:

```
QgsFeatureRequest().setSubsetOfAttributes(attributeSubset).setDistanceWithin(frame, 0)
```

Also, using an attribute subset optimize the request.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to "request" to get intersecting features, you can use Qgis processing algorithm "selectbylocation":

```
alg_params = {
    'INPUT': vectorLayer,
    'PREDICATE': 0,
    'INTERSECT': frameLayer,
    'METHOD': 0
}
processing.run("native:selectbylocation", alg_params)

features = vectorLayer.getSelectedFeatures()
```

`frameLayer` should contain the geometry you are checking for the intersection with.

For algorithm help you can use:

```
processing.algorithmHelp("native:selectbylocation")
```

Comment: As I have to use this code for a lot of layers, I don't thing using processing selectbylocation is efficient enough